# Correlation coefficient between weather conditions are zero

Tags: r, correlation, prediction, weather

I want build a model for rainfall prediction using data mining and machine learning. As one of the initial step, I computed the correlation Matrix for weather conditions including Rain Gauge, Average Temperature, Relative Humidity, Wind Speed and O3. I have used spearman and Kendall Correlation formulas and computed the correlation coefficients through RStudio.
The problem is, there is not any significant relation between Rain Gauge and other variables since all correlation coefficients are more close to zero.
I want to know that there is any other way to find out the most related variables for Gain Gauge or is it ok to use these variable even the correlation coefficients are close to zero.
Since this project work is new experience for me, please apologize for any mistakes done by me.

Comment: This question is more related to be asked here: https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/ . Make some research on it. In General the precipitation is an outcome of the complex basic atmospheric equations. What you are trying is to train a model to be a weather model. Actually there is no ML algorithm that outperforms a weather model itself.

Comment: Thank You Very Much